# Can I use core's "or Link to Existing Content" feature in my plugin?

Tags: plugin-development

When adding a link in the TinyMCE editor, you get a nice search with ajax function that searches your existing content and lets you select from it.

Is it possible/reasonable to re-use this in a plugin? If so, how would I go about doing it?

(I'm working on a Related Posts functionality, and while I can easily list ALL posts in the list, it seems it would get out of hand quickly without the ability to search/filter.)

Comment: As everything connected to TinyMCE I'd vote against doing that. Aside from that, you've got jQuery UI Autocomplete on board. Also please ensure that the question has a specific task. Currently it's "yes/no, because [opinion]".

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.

I don't understand your "also."  Is this criticism of how I phrased my question?

Comment: No, it's no criticism. I'm just trying to help to ask your question in a way that you get the most and best answers possible. Therefore I'm pushing a little to show code and make it more specific. "Is it reasonable" can easily answered with "yes/no", but this won't help you far and also would be a close reason (opinion).

Comment: "you don't explicitly mention where you'd use this" 

//

I was considering using it for a Related Posts plugin

Comment: @MadtownLems, did you work out how to do this?